# Does this sentence in Latin make sense?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, grammar-choice

I'm having some trouble with indirect speech and was wondering if my answers to these questions are correctly worded.

> Quid Priamus ante Pyrrhō praedīxit quam periit?
>   **Priamus praedixit deos Pyrrhum punituri esse propter trucidatio filii coram patre.**

> Quid dīxit Hecuba cum marītum senem arma capere vīdit?
>   **Cum maritum senem arma capere vidit, Hecuba dixit arma inutilia esse, quod solum auxilium deorum eos servare potuisse.**

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello and welcome to the site!

- **punituri:** The future participle must agree with its subject, so it should be *deos punituros*
- **potuisse:** As pointed out by Jasper in the comments, this is a subordinate clause and as such should be rendered in the subjunctive according to the consecutio temporum (c.t.). It depends on the nearest finite verb, *dixit*, and describes a simultaneous action, which calls for the imperfect subjunctive: *quod solum auxilium deorum eos servare posset*

As far as I can see, that's it for the indirect speech, aside from that:

- *propter* governs the accusative, so it should be *propter trucidationem*
- a temporal subordinate sentence with *cum* in this case should be in the subjunctive mood, so it should be *Hecuba cum videret …* (or *vidisset*, I guess that is a matter of taste). (Note: The same does not apply to *antequam* in a purely temporal meaning, which is the case here, so that is good.)

Comment: "545. A temporal clause with cum (when) and some past tense of the _indicative_ dates or defines the time at which the action of the main verb occurred." http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/cum-clauses -- So vidit is fine.

Comment: "540. The Causal particles quod and quia take the indicative, when the reason is given on the authority of the writer or speaker; the _subjunctive,_ when the reason is given on the authority of another." http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/causal-clauses -- So I'd expect potuerit.

Comment: @JasperMay I believe this is a textbook example for a *cum* that is not purely temporal. The seeing *prompted* the saying; thus the subjunctive. You are right that the *quod* clause must be in the subjunctive here. Even if it took the indicative mood in direct speech, it would have to be rendered in the subjunctive in indirect speech. I believe it should be the imperfect subjunctive though.

Comment: To be fair, I didn't quite understand the distinction made in note 3 on 546. But it doesn't seem that one action _prompting_ another has anything to do with the second needing to be subjunctive. The question "Quid dīxit Hecuba cum marītum senem arma capere vīdit?" comes from Oerberg's Exercitia Latina II, Ch. 37, Ex. 7, Nr. 13. 'Vīdit' is Oerberg's choice, and I don't want to disagree with him without a good reason.

Comment: You are right about posset. The perfect 'Dixit' is here, as it is 'ordinarily,' a secondary tense, and the dependent verb denotes an incomplete action, which means it must be in the imperfect, as you said. http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/sequence-tenses (484.2.b).

Comment: @JasperMay Hard to argue with Ørberg, but it does not strictly describe the *time*, much rather the *circumstances* of Hecuba's utterance, right? Anyway, this is rather ancillary to the question at hand, maybe a matter for a new question.

Comment: That's the distinction I didn't quite understand. I can interpret all the examples from 545 and 546 as describing both the time and the circumstances. But I agree it's better to start a new question about it.